Not able to install BoringSSL-GRPC (0.0.32)
Comparing resolved specification to the sandbox manifest
A BoringSSL-GRPC
A Firebase
A FirebaseAppCheckInterop
A FirebaseAuth
A FirebaseAuthInterop
A FirebaseCore
A FirebaseCoreExtension
A FirebaseCoreInternal
A FirebaseDynamicLinks
A FirebaseFirestore
A FirebaseFirestoreInternal
A FirebaseFunctions
A FirebaseInstallations
A FirebaseMessaging
A FirebaseMessagingInterop
A FirebaseSharedSwift
A FirebaseStorage
A Flutter
A GTMSessionFetcher
A Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK
A GoogleAppMeasurement
A GoogleDataTransport
A GoogleMaps
A GoogleUserMessagingPlatform
A GoogleUtilities
A PhoneNumberKit
A PromisesObjC
A RecaptchaInterop
A TOCropViewController
A Toast
A abseil
A cloud_firestore
A cloud_functions
A firebase_auth
A firebase_core
A firebase_dynamic_links
A firebase_messaging
A firebase_storage
A flutter_local_notifications
A fluttertoast
A gRPC-C++
A gRPC-Core
A geolocator_apple
A google_maps_flutter_ios
A google_mobile_ads
A image_cropper
A image_gallery_saver
A image_picker_ios
A leveldb-library
A libphonenumber_plugin
A nanopb
A package_info_plus
A path_provider_foundation
A permission_handler_apple
A printing
A rive_common
A share_plus
A shared_preferences_foundation
A sqflite
A url_launcher_ios
A video_player_avfoundation
Downloading dependencies

-> Installing BoringSSL-GRPC (0.0.32)
 > Git download
 > Git download
     $ /usr/local/bin/git clone https://github.com/google/boringssl.git /var/folders/fg/nkf873b15rl4gkd24n7vh5cc0000gn/T/d20240629-37065-fhuz3l --template=

[!] Error installing BoringSSL-GRPC
[!] /usr/local/bin/git clone https://github.com/google/boringssl.git /var/folders/fg/nkf873b15rl4gkd24n7vh5cc0000gn/T/d20240629-37065-fhuz3l --template=

Cloning into '/var/folders/fg/nkf873b15rl4gkd24n7vh5cc0000gn/T/d20240629-37065-fhuz3l'...
error: 2399 bytes of body are still expected
fetch-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
fatal: early EOF
fatal: fetch-pack: invalid index-pack output

/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/downloader.rb:144:in `rescue in execute_command'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/downloader.rb:141:in `execute_command'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-downloader-2.1/lib/cocoapods-downloader/base.rb:175:in `block in executable'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-downloader-2.1/lib/cocoapods-downloader/git.rb:107:in `block in clone'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/downloader.rb:175:in `block in ui_sub_action'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/downloader.rb:174:in `ui_sub_action'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-downloader-2.1/lib/cocoapods-downloader/git.rb:105:in `clone'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-downloader-2.1/lib/cocoapods-downloader/git.rb:73:in `download!'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-downloader-2.1/lib/cocoapods-downloader/base.rb:83:in `block in download'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/downloader.rb:159:in `block in ui_action'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/downloader.rb:158:in `ui_action'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-downloader-2.1/lib/cocoapods-downloader/base.rb:81:in `download'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/downloader.rb:110:in `download_source'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/downloader.rb:77:in `download_request'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/downloader/cache.rb:256:in `download'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/downloader/cache.rb:239:in `block in uncached_pod'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/downloader/cache.rb:266:in `in_tmpdir'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/downloader/cache.rb:238:in `uncached_pod'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/downloader/cache.rb:33:in `download_pod'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/downloader.rb:42:in `download'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/pod_source_downloader.rb:69:in `download!'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/pod_source_installer.rb:117:in `download_source'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/pod_source_installer.rb:67:in `install!'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:621:in `install_source_of_pod'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:539:in `block (2 levels) in install_pod_sources'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:86:in `titled_section'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:538:in `block in install_pod_sources'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:535:in `each'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:535:in `install_pod_sources'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:258:in `block in download_dependencies'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:257:in `download_dependencies'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:163:in `install!'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:52:in `run'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/bin/pod:25:in `load'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/bin/pod:25:in `<main>'

Error output from CocoaPods:
↳
Cloning into '/var/folders/fg/nkf873b15rl4gkd24n7vh5cc0000gn/T/d20240629-37065-fhuz3l'...
error: 2399 bytes of body are still expected
fetch-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
fatal: early EOF
fatal: fetch-pack: invalid index-pack output
I was trying to launch an app and it was on pod install and then, i got this error. Tried various solutions to this but still the same. The line "error: 2981 bytes of body are still expected" comes out with different numbers after "pod install".

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Dis you find the soultion? I am facing the same error on same version and pod not getting install. I have been looking for solutions for last few hours.

I didn't find the solution. I saw one which was to update Xcode but i haven't tried it as i just shifted focus to working on the project with android emulator.

I've been facing this error and fix it by doing:

open your Podfile
platform :ios, '15.0'
pod install and wait

also you need stable internet.
I hope this works for you.

This solution worked for me.
